Gradle Build failed with an exception in Windows 10: Bad Pathname
In Windows 10, run the following command in cmd, where gradle-8.10 is downloaded from gradle website
C:\Users\username>F:\gradle-8.10\bin\gradle -v

failed to run the gradle with the following errors
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.io.IOException: Bad pathname

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Bad pathname
        at org.gradle.internal.FileUtils.canonicalize(FileUtils.java:205)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildLayoutParameters.findGradleUserHomeDir(BuildLayoutParameters.java:77)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildLayoutParameters.<init>(BuildLayoutParameters.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.converter.BuildLayoutConverter.defaultValues(BuildLayoutConverter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:404)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:52)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:31)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Bad pathname
        at java.base/java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:496)
        at java.base/java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:626)
        at java.base/java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:651)
        at org.gradle.internal.FileUtils.canonicalize(FileUtils.java:203)
        ... 11 more

Don't know how to deal with this problem, even tried with gradle 7.2 and gradle 6.1.1
holp to have some solution to make the gradle works

On Windows characters like : and | are disallowed in file paths, but they can be used on Linux. If your gradle config makes use of such file paths this won't work on Windows  https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976060/150978 Try to execute gradle with command-line arguments like debug or stacktrace to find out which line of the gradle build script causes this problem.
